R Reactable + Shiny custom filtering method doesn't update rows
I tried implementing the examples for costum filtering from the reactable documentation.
While I could get those examples to work that use a JS function for the filterMethod parameter of colDef, the filterInput approaches all produce the right visuals (in my case a selectInput), when interacting with it the table did not update to display the correct rows.
I did this both in shiny and with RStudio rendering and both had the same behavior:
library(reactable)
library(shiny)

ui <- shiny::fluidPage(
  reactableOutput("cars")
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

  data <- MASS::Cars93[, c("Manufacturer", "Model", "Type", "Price")]
  
  re <- reactable(
    data,
    columns = list(
      Manufacturer = colDef(
        filterable = TRUE,
        filterInput = function(values, name) {
          tags$select(
            # Set to undefined to clear the filter
            onchange = sprintf("Reactable.setFilter('cars', '%s', event.target.value || undefined)", name),
            # "All" has an empty value to clear the filter, and is the default option
            tags$option(value = "", "All"),
            lapply(unique(values), tags$option),
            "aria-label" = sprintf("Filter %s", name),
            style = "width: 100%; height: 28px;"
          )
        }
      )
    ),
    defaultPageSize = 5
  )
  
  output$cars <- renderReactable(re)
}

shinyApp(ui, server)

This is basically the exact same code as in the reactable documentation, just inside a shiny app and without the elementId which should not be necessary. Visually this produces the expected outcome:
Screenshot of my shiny app
but then the table never updates the rows according to selected manufacturer.
The packages I have are:
attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] htmltools_0.5.8.1     sodium_1.3.1          shinyauthr_1.0.0.9000 shinyjs_2.1.0         shinyBS_0.61.1        shiny_1.8.0           reactable_0.4.4       magrittr_2.0.3       
 [9] ggplot2_3.5.1         data.table_1.14.8     dplyr_1.1.4   


This is not reproducible for me or I don't understand the problem. If I e.g. choose "Acura" within in the DropDown, then the table gets updated and only shows the two corresponding rows.
